# Looping em uma validação dentro de uma matriz

Tags: c, matriz, while

Bom, preciso validar números digitados para que a minha matriz `matriz[5][3]` aceite somente números ímpares, para isto usei dentro dos laços `for` um `do{ }while` para fazer com que outro número seja digitado caso o mesmo fosse informado como par, no entanto o programa entre em looping exibindo a mensagem do `if` mesmo quando o valor digitado está correto.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
int matriz[5][3];
int l, c;

printf ("\t Preencha a Matriz\n");

for (l=0; l<5; l++)
{
    for (c=0; c<3; c++)
    {
        printf ("\n * \n");
        printf (" Linha [%d] | Coluna [%d] \n", l+1, c+1);
        scanf ("%d", matriz[l][c]);
        do{
            printf ("\n * \n");
            if (matriz[l][c] %2 == 0)
            {
                printf ("\n Numero invalido! Informe outro");
            }
        }while(matriz[l][c] %2 == 0);
    }
}

for (l=0; l<5; l++)
{
    for (c=0; c<3; c++)
    {
        printf ("\n %d", matriz[l][c]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou refazer a entrada de dados quando o número não é ímpar.

```
for (l = 0; l < 5; l++)
{
  for (c = 0; c < 3; c++)
  {
    printf("\n * \n");
    printf(" Linha [%d] | Coluna [%d] \n", l+1, c+1);
    scanf("%d", &matriz[l][c]); // <--- faltava &
    do {
      printf ("\n * \n");
      if ((matriz[l][c] % 2) == 0)
      {
        printf("\n Numero invalido! Informe outro");
        scanf("%d", &matriz[l][c]); // <=========== faltando
      }
    } while (matriz[l][c] %2 == 0);
  }
}
```

Lógica mais simples:

```
for (l = 0; l < 5; l++)
{
  for (c = 0; c < 3; c++)
  {
    printf("\n * \n");
    printf(" Linha [%d] | Coluna [%d] \n", l+1, c+1);
    for (;;)
    {
      scanf("%d", &matriz[l][c]);
      if (matriz[l][c] & 1)
        break;
      printf("\n Numero invalido! Informe outro");
    }
  }
}
```

Entrada de dados mais robusta:

```
int n;
char buf[10];

for (l = 0; l < 5; l++)
{
  for (c = 0; c < 3; c++)
  {
    printf("\n * \n");
    printf(" Linha [%d] | Coluna [%d] \n", l+1, c+1);
    for (;;)
    {
      fgets(buf, 10, stdin); // ignorando erro quando digitado ^D/^Z
      n = sscanf(buf, "%d", &matriz[l][c]);
      if (n == 1 && (matriz[l][c] & 1))
        break;
      printf("\n Numero invalido! Informe outro");
    }
  }
}
```